# Trying to write same child to firebase twice

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to execute this if statement so the value 'Like' with the unique id is written to the database twice. The line of code is:

```
mDatabaseChemRef.child(uploadCurrent.getNumber()).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("Like");
```

and the database is stored like so:

```
  {
"467" : {
  "4ulBYMRcP4WbhTCFXHSTNwX2yPU2" : "Like"
  }
 }
```

So essentially I want the "Like" along side the same unique ID to be written twice rather than once. Below is the full code. So when the user clicks the like button I want it to like twice rather than once is there a way to write this line twice?

```
 holder.mLikebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mProcessTechLike = true;

            mDatabaseTechRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(uploadCurrent.getCategory().equals("Technology")) {

                        if (mProcessTechLike) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.child(uploadCurrent.getNumber()).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                                //delete like
                                dataSnapshot.child(uploadCurrent.getNumber()).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).getRef().removeValue();

                                mProcessTechLike = false;

                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Vote Retracted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                holder.mLikebtn.setColorFilter(null);
                            } else {

                                Resources res = mContext.getResources();
                                final int newColor = res.getColor(R.color.new_color);
                                holder.mLikebtn.setColorFilter(newColor, Mode.SRC_ATOP);

                                mDatabaseTechRef.child(uploadCurrent.getNumber()).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("Like");
                                mProcessTechLike = false;

                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Vote Counted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Why would you want to write to a database twice with the same value?

Comment: Are you trying to keep track of the amount of a times a user has clicked the like button?